# How to programmatically get current directory of a Windows command line or Windows explorer?

Tags: c++, windows, command-line, directory, explorer

I'm writing a Qt C++ program on Windows and it has registered a global shortcut <kbd>Ctrl+j</kbd>. Whenever the user press <kbd>Ctrl+j</kbd>, the program's UI will show up. When the active window is a Windows command line or a Windows explorer and the user presses <kbd>Ctrl+j</kbd>, I want to get the current directory of the Windows command line or a Windows explorer. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

For Windows Explorer you can write a BHO and communicate with it from your application. BHO - Browser Helper Object - will load into Windows Explorer process and can access anything, e.g. windows handles, text in the textboxes etc. We've done this for Internet Explorer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Do you have any short demo code? I searched around and can't find any useful information about BHO.

Comment: This is an excellent starting point https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37044/Writing-a-BHO-in-Plain-C